# Having set app to manual release can I change it to a specific date?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

So I just got a review approved from Apple and I chose manual release because I wasn't sure on the release date. But now I want to be able to upload an update to the app before release.

Apple says that to do that you need to have a specific date set.

So my question is, can I somehow set an availability date even though I checked the 'Manually release this version'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can introduce a date in the future e.g. January 1st, 2017. And then the app won't be published but you'll have a date set so you may submit an update.

Comment: I'm currently in the 'Pending developer release' status and I'm not able to find any way of setting the date of release. The only thing that I can do is press the 'Release This Version' button...Any thoughts?

Comment: Then you may select the countries you want the app to be available at (ie none; but leave one tiny country available because otherwise Apple will consider you don't want to publish the app). Then as soon as it is published you may set that future date or remove that tiny country where you wouldn't expect to have organic downloads from.